# Un'espressione per chi vuole dire "give her a chance" in italiano

Tags: translation

Come posso dire un'espressione che significa "give her a chance" in italiano?

Comment: Non ti fidi di Google? *Da*gli *una possibilità* almeno.

Comment: Sì, ma non c'è un altro modo di dire?

Comment: A parte l'uso proprio di *chance*, in alcuni casi si può dire *dare un'occasione* o *dare un'opportunità*. Se poi si tratta di *give her a chance to do something*, si può anche dire *consentile di fare qualcosa*, *permettile di fare qualcosa*.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Grazie! Puoi metterla come una risposta questo commentario!

Comment: Va bene, figurati :)

Comment: E benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Fa bene a non fidarsi di Google! ;-) “We wipe our noses” = “Spazziniamo i nostri nasi”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parte *dalle una possibilità* e l'uso proprio di *chance*, in alcuni casi si può dire *dalle un'occasione* o *dalle un'opportunità*. Se poi si tratta di *give her a chance to do something*, si può anche dire *consentile di fare qualcosa*, *permettile di fare qualcosa*. Comunque queste sono scelte valide per qualsiasi registro, mentre *chance* è colloquiale.

Come ricorda il buon @DaG, l'espressione inglese può anche avere un significato vicino a *lasciala in pace* usato come invito a non giudicarla frettolosamente. Ciò può talvolta essere espresso con *go easy on her*,  traducibile come *vacci piano con lei*.

Comment: Però “give her a chance” è molto, molto più colloquiale di “dalle una possibilità/opportunità etc.”, e ha anche un significato che si avvicina a “lasciala in pace”, “non la tormentare”. Vedi per esempio [qui](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/ways-of-telling-someone-not-to-hurry).

Comment: @DaG: Sulla prima parte concordo a metà, cioè le controparti italiane vengono usate sia formalmente che informalmente. Sulla seconda, interessante. Cosa ne pensi anche di "vacci piano con lei"?